# how to concatenate two conditions in one json extractor expression

Tags: json, jmeter

my JSON Response is look like

```
      {
      "@class":"com.dto.ElementDTO",
      "isReadOnly":false,
      "creator":"1....22b",
      "modifier":"2...2bf2",
      "id":"99999999-1DC4-5F92-7DEA-2D1A3F956C86",
      "elementProps":{      
         "duration":"month",
         "prefix":"MEN"
      },
      {
      "@class":"com.dto.ElementDTO",
      "isReadOnly":false,
      "creator":"1....58b",
      "modifier":"2..8757f2",
      "id":"44444444-1574-5F92-7D8A-2D1757956C86",
      "elementProps":{      
         "duration":"year",
         "prefix":"YEA"
      },
```

What I'm looking for is getting the **id of "@class":"com.dto.ElementDTO" which has duration:"month"**

=>  99999999-1DC4-5F92-7DEA-2D1A3F956C86

I get the all ids of "@class":"com.dto.ElementDTO" by using this expression

`$.[?(@.@class=='com.dto.ElementDTO')].id`

how can I add "duration":"month" condition to the same expression ?

Comment: For the second condition it's working by "$..elementProps[?(@.duration=='month')]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
$.[?(@.@class=='com.dto.ElementDTO' && @.elementProps.duration == 'month')].id
```

should do the trick for you.

More information:

- [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)